# C: help me understanding the output

Tags: c, output

can any one help me understanding the output of this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 1, y = 1;

    for(; y; printf("%d %d \n", x, y))
    {
        y = x++ <= 5;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the output is:

```
2 1
3 1
4 1
5 1
6 1
7 0
```

Comment: What part of the output is it you specifically don't understand?

Comment: What's the point in writing such (ugly) code?

Comment: That's a great opportunity to learn how to use your debugger and/or read your C text book.

Comment: Rather, this is a great opportunity to get rid of your source of learning C. Burn your book and/or teacher and get a new one. Don't waste time studying obfuscated code.

Comment: We can only *hope* that the teacher does this on purpose, to teach the student "Never do this again!".

Comment: @BoPersson Then they would have phrased the task as "find out what's bad in this code/how do we fix it". Sadly, there are plenty of incompetent C programming teachers out there.

Comment: It's not only a "don't do this at home, kids!" but also contains some useful lessons. e.g. what the parts in the header of a `for` loop really mean. Also that comparison operators yield a result that can be assigned to a variable and that an identifier itself can be condition of a loop.

Answer (score 5):

A `for` loop in the form of

```
for (a; b; c)
{
    d;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
{
    a;

    while (b)
    {
        d;

        c;
    }
}
```

Now if we take your loop

```
for(; y; printf("%d %d \n", x, y))
{
    y = x++ <= 5;
}
```

It is equivalent to

```
{
    // Nothing

    // Loop while y is non-zero
    while (y)
    {
        // Check if x is less than or equal to 5, assign that result to y
        // Then increase x by one
        y = x++ <= 5;

        printf("%d %d \n", x, y);
    }
}
```

Now it should hopefully be easier to understand what's going on.

Also: Remember that for boolean results (like what you get as result from a comparison), true is equal to `1`, and false is equal to `0`.

Answer (score 2):

The code is an obfuscated, ugly version of this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    bool y = true;

    while(y == true)
    {
      y = (x++ <= 5);
      printf("%d %d \n", x, (int)y);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`y` in the original code serves as a boolean. Back in the ancient days, there were no boolean type in C so it was common to use `int` instead. The expression `y = x++ <= 5;` evaluates to 0 or 1, which is equivalent to `false` or `true`.

---

Note:

While the C language allows all manner of crazy stuff, you should never write for loops as in the original code. De facto standard is to write for loops like this:

- The first clause of a for loop shall only contain iterator initialization.
- The second clause should only contain the loop condition.
- The third clause should only contain a change of the loop iterator, such as for example an increment (like i++).

A for loop that doesn't follow the above industry standard rules is badly written, no excuses.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `y = x++ <= 5;` sets `y` to `1` if `x` is less than or equal to `5`, or to `0` if `x` is greater than `5`.  It then increments `x`.  The loop stops when `y` is equal to `0`, that is, on the iteration after `x` was incremented above `5`.  Then it runs the `printf()` statement on each iteration.

You wouldn’t normally see a loop switch the loop condition and the loop body that way.  This seems to be a pathological example of how it’s technically legal.  You shouldn’t imitate it.

Answer (score 0):

y is 1 (true) as long as x <= 5 and x increases every iteration.

Rewrite your code:

```
for (int x = 1, y = 1; y; y = x <= 5, x++) {
  printf("%d %d\n", x, y);
}
```

or using while

```
int x = 1;
int y = 1;

while (y) {
  printf("%d %d\n", x, y);
  x++;
  y = x <= 5;
}
```

Comment: In the original code, x is incremented *after* the compare.

Answer (score 0):

The first component of the for loop is empty; which means values of variables haven't changed. The condition in the for loop is `y`. Which means that the loop will run till the condition `y` is true; which means till the value of y is anything other than 0.
When the value of y becomes equal to 0; the condition will become false and the loop will stop iterating.

Then comes the block execution...

```
y = x++ <= 5;
```

Here first the condition `x <= 5` is checked. Note that x++ is **post increment** and so the value of x will be incremented **after** the execution of the statement. So, if the value of x was 1 before increment; it will check `1 <= 5` and not `2 <= 5` and after the execution of the statement; the value will become 2.

After that comes the third component of for loop which is the increment part. Here,

```
printf("%d %d \n", x, y)
```

simply prints x and y.

So, what happens is; when the loop starts, both x and y are 1.

The statement

```
y = x++ <= 5;
```

is encountered, thus the condition `x++ <= 5` is checked, where x is 1. Since the condition is true; the value of y will be 1 and x will be incremented to 2. The same thing continues.... when x will be equal to 5, `x++ <= 5` will check `5 <= 5` and the condition will be true and x will be incremented to 6. Now when it goes in the loop the next time; the condition will be false and y will instead be equal to 0. Thus, now when the loop checks the condition y, the condition will be false and thus the control will flow out of the loop and thus you see the result.

Answer (score 0):

I built and dumped this code in IDA since I understand assembly better :D
This code is a bit obfuscated so here will be the normal version of it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int x = 1;
int y = 1;
while(y != 0) {
    if(x++ <= 5)
    {
      y = 1;
    } else {
      y = 0;
    }

    printf("%d %d\n",x,y);
}
```

that for loop in the source:

```
for(; y; printf("%d %d \n", x, y))
```

checks if y is a non-zero value and if it is, it will print the string you want. In the body of the loop, the result of the comparison (0 or 1) will be copied to y and the check continues.

Comment: You've built a deadloop

Answer (score 0):

Precedence of operator `<=` is higher than the operator `=`.
So, the statement:

```
y = x++ <= 5;
```

is equivalent to:

```
y = (x++ <= 5)
```

Because of post-increment `++` operator, the value of `x` returned first and then `x` is incremented.

The initial value of both `x` and `y`is `1`.

Since `y` is `1`, the `for` loop condition evaluates to `true` and the statement in the `for` loop block executed. But in the `for` loop of your code, in place of loop iterator update statement you have `printf()` statement which is printing the value of `x` and `y` after executing the loop body statements. The flow goes like this:

`1 <= 5` evaluate to `1` which is assigned to `y` and after this `x` is `2`,

Output : 2 1

`2 <= 5` evaluate to `1` which is assigned to `y` and after this `x` is `3`,

Output : 3 1

`3 <= 5` evaluate to `1` which is assigned to `y` and after this `x` is `4`,

Output : 4 1

`4 <= 5` evaluate to `1` which is assigned to `y` and after this `x` is `5`,

Output : 5 1

`5 <= 5` evaluate to `1` which is assigned to `y` and after this `x` is `6`,

Output : 6 1

`6 <= 5` evaluate to `0` which is assigned to `y` and after this `x` is `7`,

Output : 7 0

Now the value `y` is `0` and in your code, the `for` loop condition is `y` so the loop condition evaluates as `false` and loop exits.